# Integer encoder decoder for Netty

Tags: java, netty

I want to stream a series of integers across a Netty channel. Right now , in my code `channel.write(Integer.valueOf(val)` ,  I get the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unsupported message type: class java.lang.Integer` which I understand is because I do not have any integer encoder /decoder as a handler in the pipeline. Is this correct? Do I have to write my own integer decoder or there is one available to use ? Some guidance around this topic will be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, your understanding is correct.  Without an appropriate `FrameEncoder` in your pipeline, Netty is going to throw up its hands and say it doesn't know how to deal with an `Integer`.

If you want to add an off-the-shelf component, you can add an [ObjectEncoder](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/serialization/ObjectEncoder.html) and [ObjectDecoder](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/serialization/ObjectDecoder.html) to your pipeline.  Otherwise, you'll want to implement your own frame encoder and decoders.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is the case... You can also just write it in a ChannelBuffer and then write the ChannelBuffer to the Channel.

Something like:

```
ChannelBuffer buf = ChannelBuffers.buffer(4);
buf.writeInt(Integer.valueOf(val));
channel.write(buf);
```